# How do I get an accumulate of values linked to dates listed within a map-entry

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm making an application(pedometer) in android-studio where I want to list data, that I take from the realtime-databse in firebase, into a Listview within my app. Due to linking dates with steps on each day I'm left with a setup that gives "Date:steps". What do I need to do in order to accumulate all steps from each day into a subtotal that only lists the total steps without the date?

This is for a leaderboard page I'm making where I want to organize all users from highest steps(walked on all dates, starts counting from date of registration) to the lowest. I've tried to make a for loop where I call for the user and steps walked, but the steps are still linked to the date.

I've tried looking at other similar questions, example: [How do I efficiently iterate over each entry in a Java Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-java-map)

But I still can't make sense into it.

The code in question is:

```
myRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
@Override
    public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        Map<String, Map> map = (Map<String, Map>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        int i  = 0;

        for (Map.Entry<String, Map> pair : map.entrySet()) {
            Map steps = map.get("steps");

            arrayList.add(" " + map.get("username") + " " + steps);
            arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(Leaderboard.this , android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , arrayList);
      }

        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
     }
```

I want to get the output:

```
Name 200
```

with number "200" being the total amount of steps walked over all dates.
The output I am getting at the moment is:

```
Name {Date=37,Date=40,Date=12,Date=67,Date=44}
Name {Date=37,Date=40,Date=12,Date=67,Date=44}
Name {Date=37,Date=40,Date=12,Date=67,Date=44}
```

What would I need to do in order to remove the dates, and list only the values(steps) as a subtotal of all steps walked over said listed dates(per user)?

Comment: Your `map` is a `Map<String, Map>`, so what's the structure of the inner `Map`?  `<String, Integer>`?  `<String, Number>`?  Etc...

Comment: Iterate through your `map` get the values from each entry, stream it and sum it up as they're just ints.

Comment: apologies for the late reply @user2478398                                                                      Already figured out how to fix it, the inner map was a `<String, Long>`